# Oracle ADF: Refresh Form data

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am developing a web app using Oracle ADF. I have a bounded task flow. In that I have a search page like below.

[image]

I have created the above two forms using view object data controls.

Searching is performing well. But my problem is when I go some where else in my application using menus provided left side and come back to the search page , the page is not getting refreshed. I am getting a search page that contains old search results. At this point of time if I am trying to make any changes am getting some error called **"Another user with this id already modifed data ...."**. After this error my app is not running. Means what ever am trying to do its showing the same error.

So I need to make this: "When ever the user come to this form, He should get fresh form. It should not contain old search results.

Please help me. How do I achieve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Always mention your JDeveloper version so everybody knows which ADF version you are using.

Comment: thank you. Am using jdeveloper 11.1.2.4

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing it:

1) Set your task flow as ISOLATED, from Task Flow Overview tab -> Behaviour -> Share Data Control with calling task flow -> unchecked (or isolated, if you are using JDev 12c)

This will ensure you always start FRESH when accessing the page, but it will potentially create a performance overhead because entire View Object cache will be recreated (requeried) on page load. Nevertheless, it is the quickest solution.

2) You may create a default Method Call Activity in your task flow from where you may call a AM's custom method that resets the view criteria. The method will be placed on application module's implementation class and it may look like this:

```
public void initTaskFlow() {
   this.getViewObject1().executeEmptyRowSet();
}
```

This will clean the result data. If you want to reset the querying parameters as well, you can use this example:

http://www.jobinesh.com/2011/04/programmatically-resetting-and-search.html

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have checked your first solution. But am already having the same in my bounded taskflow. Under Transaction I have Always Begin New Transaction. And Share Data Control with calling task flow is unchecked. Let me try with second solution.

Comment: The fact that first solution is not working is abnormal, it means we are missing something... The only thing I can think of is perhaps there is a backing bean on session scope, holding bindings for af:table and af:query components...

Answer (score 0):

When you made any changes to any viewObject then excute this viewObject to match entity state and viewState , i think excuting viewObject will solve your issue

Ashish